# Build an apk in runtime

Tags: android, build, apk, unity-game-engine

i want to create a Windows application where you will be able to make some configurations and create own apk for downloading.

I'm using Unity 5.6 personal edition for this case.

So, my question is: is it even possible to make with Unity?

Can i create an apk in runtime?

Thx.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have an existing android project and you simply want to build the apk file? Or you don't have an android project at all and you want to create it?

Comment: It's possible... but very very complex

Comment: @riadrifai I have a project what i will build for Windows.
In windows exe, i will make some configurations and after this i want to create an apk.

Comment: @joreldraw can you please give some more information about this?

Comment: @Homa What I meant is do you have the android project present? Your windows application will access the android project in order for it to build the apk.

Comment: you can make your own compiler, your own handle for a 3th party compiler, online compiler or similar,etc. https://www.getjar.com/categories/tool-apps/Online-Compiler-804268

Comment: @riadrifai oh, i see.
Well, i can create it, but i don't want to use editor.
I know these way, but in one project just one user can build one apk, for more users i need more projects copy what is not admissible.
What why i need to build an apk just using Windows application.
I thought, will a WebGL app make this more easy?

Comment: @joreldraw i think it's a lot of work to recreate a Unity builder system.
Because there will be some 3d models, light, etc.
But thx for advise, i will search and this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after the discussion in the comments, I believe this is an approach you could take.

In case for each configuration you need a new android project, then you need to write a script that would create the android project with all its directories for you. (For this you could have a "template application" and your script could simply copy the whole directory to the desired path and undergo the modifications on the project there.)

After having the your android project modified, you can build the apk at runtime, on windows this is how you do it: Go to the app directory and run the following: `gradlew.bat buildName` where `buildName` could be something like assembleDebug or assembleRelease. For more information on the building process, please check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: Thx for advice.
It's look pretty nice, i will try it.